# How to install github repository in a specific GOPATH?

Tags: go

I have two folders for GOPATH:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/Work:$HOME/HomeWork
```

Here is their structure organization:

```
Work
    /pkg
    /src
        /github.com

HomeWork
    /pkg
    /src
        /github.com
```

By default

```
$ go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
```

will put the repository in the first GOPATH.

Now I want to install a github repository to a specific GOPATH, for example in:

```
HomeWork
    /pkg
    /src
        /github.com
            /gin-gonic
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 8):

According to Go Wiki:

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GOPATH

**Use a single GOPATH**

> Even though the GOPATH may be a list of directories, it is generally
>   correct and sufficient to use a single GOPATH for all Go code on your
>   machine. Since all packages retrieved with "go get" have a unique URL
>   (and thus a unique path on disk), having more than one GOPATH is
>   almost never necessary when building with the Go tool.

Answer (score 7):

Well I can't see an option to do this in `go get --help`.

But you could use this *nix way to achieve it:

```
$ GOPATH=$HOME/HomeWork go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
```

And your original `GOPATH` won't be changed by above command.